# Is it possible to keep the output of less on the screen after quitting?

Tags: unix, oh-my-zsh

I'm using oh-my-zsh which pipes the output of some functions like `git diff` and `git log` into `less`, whilst this is great for reading the output in the terminal. If I need to refer back to it it isn't possible after quitting with `:q`

Is there an option to preserve the current view on the file in my terminal after quitting?

Secondly, If there is an option where would I need to edit my oh-my-zsh config to ensure anything piped to less passes this option?

Comment: Does `screen -R` -> `your command` -> `CTRL+A` then `D` -> `screen -R` work?

Comment: I've checked the `man` pages for `screen` and I'm not sure this is what I'm after.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To prevent `less` from clearing the screen on exit you can start it with the option `-X`:

```
less -X FILE
```

If you want to pass this option automatically to every instance of less, you can set the `LESS` environment variable accordingly in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
export LESS="-X"
```

> **Note:**
>   If your shell has syntax coloring enabled, the `-X` option will cause your less output to display those color change escape sequences as inline `ESC` text.
>   This can be fixed by also passing the `raw-control-chars` display option, `-r`. For example:
>
> ```
> export LESS="-Xr"
> ```

This also includes instances where `less` is started by another program, for example `man`. If you want to disable this option for a single command, you can just prepend `LESS=`. For example

```
LESS= man less
```

Comment: Adding this option on macOS makes my output contain the ANSI color escape sequences but not color itself. Like this: https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/3f293X2l0s2p073q1V3y/Image%202017-08-20%20at%206.56.51%20PM.png. Any hints on how to fix it?

Comment: Just for completeness, this did the trick for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62850/30787

Comment: `export LESS=-Xr` as described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187559/303178 fixed that for me @kolrie

Answer (score 19):

For Git specifically, this can be handled with the following

```
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global core.pager 'less -Xr'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using git in terminal. Thanks!